# Some objects refuse to be destroyed (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, rake

I'm running a rake task to destroy all of my "course" objects:

```
task :destroy_all_classes => :environment do 
  Course.all.each do |c| 
    c.destroy
  end 
end
```

This destroys most of the courses, but 12 remain (out of 40+). What might be preventing me from deleting them?

If I try deleting each course manually, through the console, I get this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :030 > Course.find(1).destroy
 => false
```

Comment: Can you do:
c = Course.find(1); c.destroy; puts c.errors.inspect

Comment: Ah, that did it! It revealed that I had at least one "line_item" object that belonged to each of the courses that refused to delete. The output of .inspect was "{:base=>[\"Line Items present\"]}". Deleting the line_items first worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable cascade destroy.

Course have at lest one "has many"or "has one" relation with another model.Something like

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :somethings
  has one : something
end
```

make it

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :somethings, :dependent => :destroy
  has one :something, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

You can also use

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :something, :allow_destroy => true
```

Best of luck !!!

Comment: Happy to Help You. You are Welcomed!